# not able to implement multi selection with chosen feature using yadcf 0.9.1 js file

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

> @Daniel Reznick' 
>   Hi, I want to implement that  multi selection with chosen feature using yadcf
>   0.9.1 or any other version js file for each column filtering, but it's showing only single selection on my local.
>   [image of current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkLM8.jpg)

[`<https://jsfiddle.net/prats1251/k2grtsd0/1/>`](https://jsfiddle.net/prats1251/k2grtsd0/1/)

> Thanks.

Comment: if still relevant - provide a cleaner jsfiddle test page with datatables / yadcf / chosen, atm your test page contains tons of irrelevant stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/zpz15upo/6/), 
you had several issues, 1) invalid use of yadcf api call , invalid loading order of resources / no resources of chosen were present in your test page.

When using the Capital letter *D* api of datatables you must use the

`yadcf.init(oTable, [{}])` instead of `.yadcf([{}])`